# index to navigate to parts of the video

Tags: video, youtube

I would like to create a page with a youtube video embedded. The catch is I would like to display a list of options alongside the video and clicking on these should redirect the seek to that part in the video

Note: I found that I could hyperlink the options with youtube link that has start and end time but clicking on it reloads the entire video and what I am looking to do is just adjust seek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Youtube API provides a seek method to allow you specify a time to seek to:

- player.seekTo(seconds:Number, allowSeekAhead:Boolean):Void

It will play the video if the video was playing or seek to that point and stay paused if the video was paused.

You can have your page/app set up so that when someone selects one of your options alongside the video it calls this method.

More info on the API is available at:

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls